# Assigning a Seam Component as An event handler to GWT Button

Tags: gwt, seam, gwt2, seam2

I am designing a web application which will use gwt and seam.

I have gone through the examples provided by Seam  docs.

There the proposed solution is to use remoting to hook gwt widgets to seam components.

Is there any other technique by which this can be achieved ?